# Fullcalendar-Don't display any events on sundays

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am using `fullcalendar-2.2.7-yearview`. All working fine but I don't want to show the events on Sundays.

For example is I am having an event from October 1,2016 to October 22,2016 which includes two Sundays in that. But I don't want to mark any events on Sunday. Also I don't want to hide Sundays from calendar too.

Please suggest me a way to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're not interested in Sundays then why not just hide Sunday from the calendar? What's the problem with doing that? Otherwise I think you'll have to split your event up in to Mon-Sat blocks.

Comment: You can split events up manually. Here's a link showing how to do that for skipping weekends (may need further refinement/testing) http://stackoverflow.com/a/35634746/5360631

Answer (score 0):

```
eventRender: function(event)
             {
                 if(moment(event.start).isoWeekday() == 7)
                 {
                     //If the event is on a Sunday, don't render it.
                     return false;
                 }
             }
```

Edit: I just reread the issue and didn't realize that this would be for multi-day events that extend through Sundays. I guess the solution there would be to split the events as suggested above and then use the method here to avoid rendering on sundays.

Comment: Thank you for ur help sir. I managed to split the events without Sunday and eliminated sunday while generating JSON. Its just working fine sir.